# What will happen if millions of users try to lon in to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

I'm using Asp.net Webforms. I want to know what will happen when millions of users try to log-in **concurrently**. I'm using webforms authentication.

Comment: You would need a LOT more details before anyone could even begin to answer that question, and without load testing, there's really no way to know

Comment: The same thing that would happen if one user tries to logon.  The application will respond using the resources at its disposal.  If the available resources are insufficient, the system may fail to respond in a timely manner.

Answer (score 1):

From IIS perspective - depending on this settings https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560842(VS.100).aspx next will happen:

- (N = **maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU * [Server CPU count]**) N threads will be created to process first N requests.
- **requestQueueLimit** requests will be queued and will wait for available threads.
- the rest will receive denial of service response.